# Interaction terms and effect sizes in multiple regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, interaction, effect-size

I know there are similar questions on here, but I can't quite find an answer that covers all of what I need. I am running multiple regression in r with two predictor variables and sometimes an interaction term e.g.:

```
model1 = lm(Measure1 ~ Variable 1 + Variable 2)
model2 = lm(Measure1 ~ Variable 1 + Variable 2 + Variable2:Variable 3)
```

I am first wondering, what is the best way to calculate the effect size specifically of variable 2 in both instances. I know because the second formula includes an interaction I can't necessarily use the standard coefficient values, and I'd like to get the effect size in a consistent way between the two formulas. Also, if it's important, the DV is continuous, but the variables are dummy coded variables (e.g. on/off a drug and gender). Along these lines, is there a good way to determine when I *should* use an interaction in the equation when I have *many* dependent variables I want to look at? Creating a plot of each manually doesn't seem like the most efficient way to do so…

Answer (score 2):

If you include an interaction term, then "the" effect no longer exists. Instead you have multiple effects: one for each level of the other variable with which you created the interaction. This is the very point of including interactions, so there is no way around it.

Comment: So then when including an interaction term there is no way to report the effect size?

Comment: no, that is not what I said. There are now multiple effect sizes, so you need to find a way to report them all. If these are two binary variables you can just report them, if they are continuous variables you need to think about graphs.

Comment: Okay, I see. What is the best measure to use as the effect in this type of analysis? From my understanding I can't use the coefficient values… (I'm using r specifically)

Comment: To repeat, there is no "the" effect when including an interaction; there are many, and you need to report all of them. So if you want to report one effect size you should not include an interaction. Alternatively, if you need an interaction, you need to report multiple effect sizes. It is one or the other. You cannot have an interaction and report only one effect size.

Comment: Yes, I understand there would be an effect for each independent variable used (including interaction variables). I was just trying to figure out the best methodology to calculate this. For instance, Cohen's d vs. partial R-squared, and how I can do so using the R program. I am going with partial R-squared, but if you have any input on this let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not exactly what I said, but I am afraid that repeating the same thing over and over is not very helpful. Instead I will just suggest that you read again very carefully what I have written, and compare that with what you have written and see where the differences are.

Comment: It seems like we are just disputing semantics here. I understand what you have said: there are many effects and I would need to report all of them. That is not what I have been trying to get at however. In order to calculate all of the effects, there are certain statistics that need to be run, and I am trying to figure out what the best method for that is.

Comment: Do you use R? Perhaps it would help to make things less complicated (e.g. my first example). Ignoring any and all interactions, what is the best way to calculate an effect size for variable x in the following regression: model1 = lm(Measure1 ~ Variable x + Variable y). Some statistical programs might just tell you the effect of x in the output you receive. However, R does not work that way. You have to know what to ask from it, and that is what I've been trying to figure out.

Comment: The best effect size depends on what you want to do with it and to whom you have to communicate your results. If the problem is with R than you can either switch to another program or get a book and read up on it. [This one](http://www.sagepub.com/books/Book233899) is quite accesible (well, I own the previous edition).

Comment: Thanks, I will check out that text! In the mean time, can you elaborate, or give an example on using a specified effect measure in one case but not another. In regards to what I am wanting to do, I want to calculate the effect size to understand the impact of a given independent variable on the dependent (just because something is significant doesn't mean it has much of a biologically meaningful effect). Ultimately I would be communicating these results to biologists.

Comment: We need much more information than that to meaningfully answer that. To figure that out in a reasonable amount of time, you will probably have to meet face to face. There is only so much that is possible on an internet forum. So I suggest you find someone near you and schedule an appointment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using cohen's d in a very similar case to yours. It is shown that an ln(odds ratio) can be converted to effect size by dividing it by 1.81"
This can help: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1097-0258(20001130)19:22%3C3127::AID-SIM784%3E3.0.CO;2-M